# How to retrieve a lost text after your browser didn't submit the text

Tags: forum

Sometimes, I type in some text and submit, then it's not submitted for some reason or another, and when I go back, the text is lost. Is there a way to retreive this lost text?

is there a "re-type what I type in the last hour?" program?

Comment: Which browser?        .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Firefox, there is an add-on named "Lazarus" which gives you exactly what you want: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6984

This is from the description of the add-on:

> Never lose anything you type into a
>   web form again! Lazarus securely
>   auto-saves all forms as you type, so
>   after a crash, server timeout, or
>   whatever, you can go back to the form,
>   right click, "recover form", and
>   breathe a sigh of relief.